Prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, g(x)=-9e^x+x^3+3x^2+5x+6\leq 0$

How to prove $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}. g(x)=-9e^x+x^3+3x^2+5x+6\leq 0$?

$g'(x)=-9e^x+3x^2+6x+5$ and $g''(x)=-9e^x+6x+6\leq -3e^x<0$, so $g'(x)$ is monotonically decreasing and has unique zero $x_0$.
$g'(-2)>0$ and $g'(-1)<0$ so $-2<x_0<-1$
because of $g'(x_0)=0$, I got $9e^x=3x^2+6x+5$, so $g(x_0)=x_0^3-x_0+1$.
Let $h(x)=x^3-x+1$, I got $h(x)$ is monotonically increasing in $(-2, -1)$, so $g(x_0)=h(x_0)<h(-1)=1$, but I want get $g(x_0)<0$.
I can only get $x_0\in(-1.35, -1)$ but $h(-1)>0$，How can I prove it?

@user2661923 $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, e^x\geq x+1$. your conclusion that $r(x)>0:x>0$, and $r(x)<0:x<0$ maybe is $r'(x)>0,x>0$, and $r'(x)<0, x<0$. That means $r(x) \geq r(0)=0$

@S.Y.Li Your comment nailed what I was thinking.  You're right; it was my blindness.  I have therefore deleted my first comment.

Alternative solution (inspired by @Claude Leibovici's nice answer)
It suffices to prove that
$$g(x) + \frac{1}{120}x^2 \le 0,$$
or
$$\frac{x^3 + 3x^2 + 5x + 6 + \frac{1}{120}x^2}{\mathrm{e}^x} \le 9.$$
Let $f(x) := \frac{x^3 + 3x^2 + 5x + 6 + \frac{1}{120}x^2}{\mathrm{e}^x}$. We have
$$f'(x) = -\frac{(3x + 4)(40x^2 - 53x + 30)}{120\mathrm{e}^x}.$$
Since $40x^2 - 53x + 30 > 0$, we have
$f'(x) > 0$ on $x < -4/3$, and $f'(x) < 0$ on $x > -4/3$. Thus, $f(x) \le f(-4/3) = \frac{104}{45}\mathrm{e}^{4/3} < 9$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
We are done.

Nice trick! I think this is what I want to do.

@S.Y.Li I think it is the so-called "shift of extrema". I used this trick for this question as well.

Consider the function
$$a(x)=\frac {x^3+3x^2+5x+6  }{e^x}$$ and look when it shows a double root.
This gives
$$a'(x)= -\frac{x^3-x+1}{e^x}=0$$
The cubic equation has only one real root
$$x=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)=-1.324718$$
At this point
$$x^3+3x^2+5x+6 =(x-1)+3x^2+5x+6=3 x^2+6 x+5$$ makes
$$a_{\text{max}}=8.711990$$
Since you look for $a(x)=9$, this is the end of the story.

Nice. We may avoid using the roots of cubic.

You already know that you only need to check that $g(x)<0$ for $x\in[-2,-1]$.
Let
$$
f(u)=e^2\,g(-2+u)=(u^3 - 3u^2 + 5u)e^2 - 9e^u
$$
and check $f(u)<0$ for $u\in [0,1]$.
Since all terms of Taylor expansion of $e^u$ are positive,
\begin{align}
f(u)&\le \tilde f(u):=(u^3 - 3u^2 + 5u)e^2 - 9\left(1+u+\frac{u^2}2+\frac{u^3}6\right)
\end{align}
for $u\ge 0$. It's easy to find the critical points of $\tilde f(u)$ as
$$
\tilde f'(u)=-9 + (3u^2 - 6u + 5)e^2 - 9u^2/2 - 9u.
$$
The solution of this quadratic equation are $x_0:=\frac{6 \,{\mathrm e}^{2}+9-\sqrt{306 e^2-81-24e^4}}{6 e^2-9}=0.6748...$ and $2.344...$ so the maximum of $\tilde f(u)$ for $u\in [0,1]$ is achieved at $x_0$ and equals
$$
\tilde f(x_0)=\frac{\left(102 \,{\mathrm e}^{2}-27-8e^4\right) \sqrt{-24 \,{\mathrm e}^{4}+306 \,{\mathrm e}^{2}-81}+81 \,{\mathrm e}^{2}-972 \,{\mathrm e}^{4}+108 \,{\mathrm e}^{6}-243}{9 \left(2 \,{\mathrm e}^{2}-3\right)^{2}}=-0.476...
$$
Since $f(x)\le \tilde f(x)$ your statement is proven.
